# Get user profile from google plus works inconsistently in android

Tags: android

I am using the following code for getting user information from Google plus,
but it sometimes returns null. Please tell me what is wrong in this or suggest another code.

```
private void fetchNameFromProfileServer() throws IOException, JSONException {
    String token = fetchToken();
    URL url = new URL("https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/userinfo?access_token="+token);
    HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    int sc = con.getResponseCode();
    if (sc == 200) {
        InputStream is = con.getInputStream();
        GOOGLE_USER_DATA = readResponse(is);
        is.close();
        System.out.println("Vr: In fetchNameFromProfileServer() of AbstractGetNameTask aync task.");
        mActivity.finish();
        Intent intent=new Intent(mActivity,Profile_Activity.class);
        intent.putExtra("email_id", mEmail);
        mActivity.startActivity(intent);
        mActivity.finish();
        return;
    } else if (sc == 401) {
        GoogleAuthUtil.invalidateToken(mActivity, token);
        onError("Server auth error, please try again.", null);

        return;
    } else {
        onError("Server returned the following error code: " + sc, null);
        return;
    }
}

private static String readResponse(InputStream is) throws IOException {
    ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    byte[] data = new byte[2048];
    int len = 0;
    while ((len = is.read(data, 0, data.length)) >= 0) {
        bos.write(data, 0, len);
    }
    return new String(bos.toByteArray(), "UTF-8");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this code :

```
    private void getProfileInformation() {
    try {
        if (Plus.PeopleApi.getCurrentPerson(mGoogleApiClient) != null) {
            Person currentPerson = Plus.PeopleApi
                    .getCurrentPerson(mGoogleApiClient);
            String personName = currentPerson.getDisplayName();
            String personPhotoUrl = currentPerson.getImage().getUrl();
            String personGooglePlusProfile = currentPerson.getUrl();
            String email = Plus.AccountApi.getAccountName(mGoogleApiClient);

            Log.e(TAG, "Name: " + personName + ", plusProfile: "
                    + personGooglePlusProfile + ", email: " + email
                    + ", Image: " + personPhotoUrl);

            txtName.setText(personName);
            txtEmail.setText(email);

            // by default the profile url gives 50x50 px image only
            // we can replace the value with whatever dimension we want by
            // replacing sz=X
            personPhotoUrl = personPhotoUrl.substring(0,
                    personPhotoUrl.length() - 2)
                    + PROFILE_PIC_SIZE;

            new LoadProfileImage(imgProfilePic).execute(personPhotoUrl);

        } else {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "Person information is null", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

See this link [enter link description here](http://www.androidhive.info/2014/02/android-login-with-google-plus-account-1/)  it can help you